# Is there an available event (in xamarin or platform-specific) which can be used to listen to any change in device time by the user?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin Forms application and the requirement to listen to device time-related changes done by the user. Is there any available event either in Xamarin or specific platforms (android, iOS and UWP) which can serve the purpose?

Expected Scenario: User sets the time through settings of the device. Xamarin application gets notified of the event that time was changed.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 1):

Android:

You could register a `Broadcast Receiver` with an Intent Filter `Intent.ActionTimeChanged`.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionTimeChanged })]
public class DeviceTimeChanged : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Work that should be done when the device boots.     
    }
}
```

Broadcast Receiver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers

Intent.ActionTimeChanged: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.intent.actiontimechanged?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

iOS:

For ios, you could use `NSSystemClockDidChange` or `applicationSignificantTimeChange`

NSSystemClockDidChange:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1414255-nssystemclockdidchange

applicationSignificantTimeChange:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622992-applicationsignificanttimechange?language=objc